# Looping out JSON into a template via the $.ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

I'm having an issue looping out my returned JSON data which looks like this

```
{
 "max": "12",
 "page": null,
 "total": 12,
 "items": [
    {
    "14bfa6bb14875e45bba028a21ed38046": {
        "id": "69",
        "title": "Protein Packed Meatloaf",
        "image": "nopic.jpg",
        "link": "protein-packed-meatloaf.html",
        "description": "This meatloaf is packed with protein to help your muscles grow.",
        "category": "Dinner",
        "comment_count": "0 Comments",
        "ingredient_count": 7,
        "ate_this": 0,
        "rating": "5",
        "nutritional": {
            "calories": "205.00",
            "protein": "20.55",
            "carbohydrate": "7.70",
            "fat": "9.64"
        }
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
$("select,input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){ inits(); });
$("input[type=text],textarea").keystop(function(){ inits(); });

b = "form#recipeSearch";
c = $(b).attr('action') + '?r';
f = "#searchResults";

function inits(){

    console.log('Search Init');

    $.ajax({
        url: c,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(b).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(l) {},
        success: function(response) {

            console.log('Link: ' + c + $(b).serialize());
            //response = JSON.stringify(response);

            if (response) {
                $(f).empty();
                $.each(response, function(i,data){

                    var template = '   <div id="item-' + items.id + '" class="list-item"> '
                             + '       <a href="' + items.link + '" rel="popover" title="' + items.title + '" data-content="' + items.description + '"><img src="' + items.image + '" alt="' + items.title + '"></a>'
                             + '       <div id="title-description">'
                             + '           <h4><a href="' + items.link + '">' + items.title+ '</a></h4>'
                             + '           ' + items.rating + ' &nbsp;'
                             + '           <span class="webSymbol">,</span> Posted in <a href="' + items.category + '">' + items.category + '</a> &nbsp;'
                             + '           <span class="webSymbol">&#178;</span> ' + items.ingredient_count + ' &nbsp;'
                             + '           <span class="webSymbol">U</span> ' + items.ate_this + ' &nbsp;'
                             + '           <span class="webSymbol">c</span> ' + items.comment_count + ''
                             + '           <p id="description">' + items.description + '</p>'
                             + '       </div>'
                             + '   </div>';

                    $(f).html(template);

                });
            }
        },
        error: function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            console.log('Link: ' + c + $(b).serialize());
            console.log('Error: ' + e.toString() + ' - ' + jqxhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I'm stuck as to how to loop out each item, I always get undefined or an error. Any direction is appreciated.

**Stack Trace from Chrome I believe is**:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined 
(anonymous function) min.js:521
e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
$.ajax.success min.js:519
o jquery.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
w jquery.min.js:4
d
```

Comment: Start with: console.log(response);

Comment: I believe instead of `g` there should be `response.items`

Comment: Code's been updated with stack trace as well.

Comment: Did you inspect the response in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to do something like this:

```
if(response.items) { // Are there items in the response?
  $.each(response.items, function(idx,item) { // For each item in the array.
    // Now you can reference things like this.
    item.id;
    item.link;
  }
}
else {
  // Log stuff. It's a good habit to start doing.
  console.log("There are no items in the response.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had it as you have it, but then I receive -- Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: Are you debugging this in Chrome or Firebug? Don't you have a stack trace to look at? You should be able to see exactly what line your error is on.

Comment: Fixed the code above, getting items is not defined. I'm using Chrome.. Added the stack trace into my original question..

Comment: Ok I made some changes. Try that.

Comment: I removed the array parent after the items array starts and it displays just one item now, not the multiples that are returned.

Comment: Issue resolved, I was using .html instead of prepend which now displays all of the items. Any suggestions on how to implement pagination on the jQuery side of things, the php is already there and returns the max to display, and the total amount of results and what page your on (if any is set via our jQuery)

Comment: Note: It's not really a good habit to log stuff in production code. That will crash the script in browsers that doesn't have a debug console.

Comment: `if(production) { console.log = function() {} }`

Comment: Any suggestions on where to start with pagination on the jQuery side. I already return max/total/page (if its sent) from the php file.

Comment: That's another question, you should create a new question when you get stuck. Pretty sure jQuery has a pagination plugin. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination